# SPF in hotmail are not used

Tags: email, postfix, spam, spf

I have a problem with Hotmail provider, all mail sent from my server goes to SPAM folder. I Have added a correct SPF to my domain example.com but into the headers is not used (spf=none) and the token smtp.mailfrom is ambiguos (example.com@mailserver.com)

```
    x-store-info:4r51+eLowCe79NzwdU2kR3P+ctWZsO+J
    Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=none (sender IP is *.*.*.*) smtp.mailfrom=example.com@mailserver.com; dkim=none header.d=example.com; x-hmca=none header.id=info@example.com
    X-SID-PRA: info@example.com
    X-AUTH-Result: NONE
    X-SID-Result: NONE
    X-Message-Status: n:n
    X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MjtHRD0yO1NDTD02
    X-Message-Info: 11chDOWqoTkBYPj0PkrvLTnWXZD58brruBYhQMQX0c2K8hTlww0C/c26ZToT9/NwYg889VtfffaVfjH7UvFaHNfBqJpEZIUovILiBhGqKUNkCLXCqUsgCBGcbeYOCSzEkog3t7lAJ4PGbJTnUCyuU8ijLlHkSu0stWqrgum9Pi128HZHu+C63o7P08aJG+jyoxpCvrJ6OFMIH//i+v3sD8qLWQ26dlMkmMk1DiwuXwFHByZPO2vyeQ==
    Received: from mailserver.com ([*.*.*.*]) by COL004-MC5F33.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.23143);
 Fri, 4 Mar 2016 06:41:13 -0800
    Received: by mailserver.com (Postfix, from userid 1012)
id 81AAE4B2D5; Fri,  4 Mar 2016 15:41:11 +0100 (CET)
    To: mymail@outlook.com
    Subject: the subject
    X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:test.php
    From: info@example.com
    Reply-To: webmaster@example.com
    X-Mailer: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11
    Message-Id: <20160304144111.81AAE4B2D5@mailserver.com>
    Date: Fri,  4 Mar 2016 15:41:11 +0100 (CET)
    Return-Path: example.com@mailserver.com
    X-OriginalArrivalTime: 04 Mar 2016 14:41:13.0476 (UTC) FILETIME=[E692AC40:01D17623]

    hello
```

What's wrong into this header? Mail sent to others provider (ex. gmail) are correctly setted.

Comment: If you recently updated your SPF records you may simply need to be a little patient, since they are essentially DNS records delays may simply be the result of caching...

Comment: It seems you are sending email using some php script. So check the script settings. It is setting some headers wrong. You can also check by sending mails using a regular client, like outlook, thunderbird etc.

Comment: I set SPF record 2 days ago, before it was not setted. 

smtp.mailfrom is correct? It seems wrong, I suppose is **info@example.com** and not **example.com@mailserver.com**

Answer (score 0):

Hotmail is know to have its own spam check metric.

**No one can answer you**, as even hotmail support does not answer such request to get unlisted as spam or to know the metric.

Some think its a background check on the domain (like aging), but its speculation.

For your info, even some official microsoft email I have got received in my spam box in my hotmail account. (like the monthly patch resume, which is from a @microsoft.com account)